# how to handle 2 splitpoints that require.ensure the same large module?

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to get a lazy-loading app setup which only loads the things it needs to as you navigate around. I'm using webpack's codesplitting with require.ensures and react-router but I'm having a problem (or a misunderstanding). 2 of my routes require('lodash') but it is being downloaded twice, once per each require.ensure. here it is running: https://examples-bqxmpefrny.now.sh/huge-apps/ and here is the actual commit github.com/ryankshaw/react-router/commit/a97d77f (I also tried it in webpack 2.1.0-beta.25 and it still didn't work like I thought it should github.com/ryankshaw/react-router/commit/9396830)

what do I need to do so it only downloads 'loash' once? or is that just not something webpack can do?

In other words, webpack doesn't do what I thought it would. If you require a large module in 2 different require.ensures it will bundle it into each chunk, meaning the browser ends up downloading the code for that module twice. I would expect it to be smart enough to split the module that is shared between the 2 require.ensures out into its own chunk and load it in paralell with either of the 2 split-point chunks that need it. is there a way to get webpack to do that? is this considered a bug?

Note: I don't want to just use the commonsChunkPlugin because even though that module is shared between 2 splitpoints, I don't want to put it in the commons chunk and load it on every page (imagine a large app with much bigger dependencies than just lodash, where even if different parts of the app use the module, it would be wastful to force the vast majority of the other parts of your app to download that file. And where you could have multiple splitpoints on the same page that use the module)

Answer (score 0):

The same issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/162) and they came up with a plugin called [AgressiveMergePlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/agressive-merging) which will help you to avoid downloading your library twice.

> imagine a large app with much bigger dependencies than just lodash,
>   where even if different parts of the app use the module, it would be
>   wastful to force the vast majority of the other parts of your app to
>   download that file

For the above quoted statement, you can go with Webpack version >= 2.0 which has [Tree-shaking](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html) feature to bundle only the `require`d or `import`ed modules/exports.

Comment: The AggressiveMergingPlugin isn't what I want because I don't want the other routes to download 'lodash' since they don't use it. Also, I pushed a new example: https://examples-isxmblhaqe.now.sh/huge-apps/grades in that case the Calendar link require's both 'lodash' and  'moment' and the Grades link requires 'lodash' and 'jquery'. When I go to the Calendar link, I'd expect it to download the common bundle, another chunk that contains just lodash (which is shared between Calendar and Grades) and another chunk that includes the modules exclusive to this page (ie: 'jquery' and code for that page)

Comment: and Tree-shaking doesn't help me because I'm not trying to elimnate dead code. it _is_ required in some places, I just want to make sure that it is only downloaded when it is required. in fact, all of these examples are actually using webpack 2 beta, see: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/compare/cbd1a95b2...9396830